# How to connect redis with SSL in microstreams on springboot using one.microstream.afs.blobstore.types.BlobStoreFileSystem?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-webflux, reactive, microstream

We are using spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive. our redis server has ssl protective with ssl certrificate. how to create a RedisClient bean with these configuration to use in microstreams?

We have created below Configuration and bean not sure how to to inject LettuceConnectionFactory in redis client.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisConfig {
@Value("${spring.redis.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${spring.redis.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.redis.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.redis.ssl:false}")
private boolean sslEnabled;

@Value("${spring.redis.ssl-cert-file}")
private String pemFile;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() throws IOException {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(password);

    LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder =
            LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();

    if (sslEnabled){
        SslOptions sslOptions = SslOptions.builder()
                .trustManager(resourceLoader.getResource("file:"+pemFile).getFile())
                .build();

        ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions
                .builder()
                .sslOptions(sslOptions)
                .protocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.RESP3)
                .build();

        lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder
                .clientOptions(clientOptions)
                .useSsl();
    }
    LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder.build();
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration);
}

@Bean
public RedisClient redisClient() {
    RedisURI redisUri = RedisURI.Builder.redis(host, port)
            .withSsl(true)
            .build();
    return RedisClient.create(redisUri);
} 
}
```

Getting below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'streamApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'updateDataPeriodically': Error creating bean with name 'updateDataPeriodically' defined in file [/Users/id/Downloads/stream/build/classes/java/main/com/micro/stream/UpdateDataPeriodically.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'testDataRepo' defined in file [/Users/id/Downloads/stream/build/classes/java/main/com/micro/stream/TestDataRepo.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'rootObject': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageManager': Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    ... 20 common frames omitted\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testDataRepo' defined in file [/Users/id/Downloads/stream/build/classes/java/main/com/micro/stream/TestDataRepo.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'rootObject': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageManager': Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testDataRepo' defined in file [/Users/id/Downloads/stream/build/classes/java/main/com/micro/stream/TestDataRepo.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'rootObject': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageManager': Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    ... 33 common frames omitted\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rootObject': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageManager': Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rootObject': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storageManager': Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    ... 47 common frames omitted\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defineStorageManager' defined in class path resource [com/micro/stream/MicroConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    ... 62 common frames omitted\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    ... 75 common frames omitted\
Caused by: one.microstream.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionSource: null\
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.readTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.java:76) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.readTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.java:49) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.loadTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.java:198) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDictionaryProvider$Default.provideTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryProvider.java:77) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDictionaryProvider$Caching.provideTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryProvider.java:130) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager$Exporting.internalProvideTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager.java:248) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager$Abstract.ensureTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager.java:111) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager$Abstract.provideTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryManager.java:125) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.synchInternalInitialize(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:965) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeHandlerManager$Default.initialize(PersistenceTypeHandlerManager.java:957) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.storage.embedded.types.EmbeddedStorageFoundation$Default.createEmbeddedStorageManager(EmbeddedStorageFoundation.java:803) ~[microstream-storage-embedded-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.storage.embedded.types.EmbeddedStorageFoundation.createEmbeddedStorageManager(EmbeddedStorageFoundation.java:178) ~[microstream-storage-embedded-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at com.micro.stream.MicroConfig.defineStorageManager(MicroConfig.java:58) ~[main/:na]\
    at com.micro.stream.MicroConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$defineStorageManager$0(<generated>) ~[main/:na]\
    at com.micro.stream.MicroConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]\
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [one.microstream.storage.types.StorageManager]: Factory method 'defineStorageManager' threw exception with message: null\

    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
    at com.micro.stream.MicroConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.defineStorageManager(<generated>) ~[main/:na]\
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]\
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]\
Caused by: one.microstream.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionSource: null\

    ... 76 common frames omitted\
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to <IP_ADDRESS>/<unresolved>:6378\
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]\
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]\
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]\
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]\
    at one.microstream.afs.redis.types.RedisConnector$Default.commands(RedisConnector.java:152) ~[microstream-afs-redis-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.redis.types.RedisConnector$Default.blobs(RedisConnector.java:171) ~[microstream-afs-redis-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.blobstore.types.BlobStoreConnector$Abstract.internalFileExists(BlobStoreConnector.java:315) ~[microstream-afs-blobstore-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.blobstore.types.BlobStoreConnector$Abstract.fileExists(BlobStoreConnector.java:692) ~[microstream-afs-blobstore-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.blobstore.types.BlobStoreIoHandler$Default.subjectFileExists(BlobStoreIoHandler.java:136) ~[microstream-afs-blobstore-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.blobstore.types.BlobStoreIoHandler$Default.subjectFileExists(BlobStoreIoHandler.java:65) ~[microstream-afs-blobstore-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.types.AIoHandler$Abstract.exists(AIoHandler.java:532) ~[microstream-afs-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.afs.types.AFile.exists(AFile.java:145) ~[microstream-afs-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    at one.microstream.persistence.internal.PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.readTypeDictionary(PersistenceTypeDictionaryFileHandler.java:56) ~[microstream-persistence-08.01.00-MS-GA.jar:na]\
    ... 98 common frames omitted\
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]\
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to <IP_ADDRESS>/<unresolved>:6378\

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]\
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1559) ~[netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1405) ~[netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246) ~[netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295) ~[netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\

    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]\
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]\
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]\
    ... 31 common frames omitted\
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]\
    ... 36 common frames omitted\

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}
```

Comment: Hi, it is important to print the whole call stack, because the spring has the root problem on the end of the call stack. He cannot make some beans, but the reason is below at the end. Please add it to the question or comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Updated the question. Please help us to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with Microstream or Spring. It's that the Java Client cannot validate your certificate on Redis. So either you have to upload a public key to the JVM or use some certificate on a publicly recognized authority that is already in the JVM.

for example:

java8

> <JAVA_HOME>/bin/keytool -importcert -alias <server_name> -keystore
> <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file public.crt

java 11

> <JAVA_HOME>/bin/keytool -importcert -alias <server_name> -keystore
> <JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts -file public.crt